# How to fix error of field creation in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, migration, laravel-5.3

I have a migration that correctly created table at local vagrant server, but when I tried migrate at VPS with nginx it encounters strange error.

Local env is Vagrant/homestead (I don't know OS, sorry), VPS env is Debian 8, nginx. Laravel version 5.3
Migrations have to create 12 tables, but problem encountered before the end process, so 10 tables only created. By the way it shows that env and other settings is OK (I think) and just in 1 table 1 field is error

this is creation code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('vicards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('visi_slug', 100);
            $table->unique('visi_slug', 'visi_slug_unique');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->index('user_id', 'cards_user_id_index');
            $table->string('user_slug', 100);
            $table->index('user_slug', 'cards_user_slug_index');
            $table->string('avatar', 44)->default(0);
            $table->string('header', 80);
            $table->string('price', 12);
            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('pictures'); // 5 pics * 20 symbols + 4 commas
            $table->text('videos'); // 3 videos * 41 symbols + 2 commas
            $table->text('contacts'); //
            $table->text('links'); // links separated by commas
            $table->text('styles'); // object serialized
            $table->tinyInteger('actual', 1)->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

problem invokes this field

```
$table->tinyInteger('actual', 1)->default(0);
```

artisan interprets it in:

```
 `actual` tinyint not null default '0' auto_increment primary key
```

and off-course it is error because 'auto_increment primary key' already exist - 1st field

Expected result - regular table creation.

I got error:

" [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'actual' (SQL: create table `vicards` (`id` int unsigned not
  null auto_increment primary key, `visi_slug` varchar(100) not null, `user_id` int not null, `user_slug` varchar(100) not null, `avatar` varchar
  (44) not null default '0', `header` varchar(80) not null, `price` varchar(12) not null, `description` text not null, `pictures` text not null,
  `videos` text not null, `contacts` text not null, `links` text not null, `styles` text not null, `actual` tinyint not null default '0' auto_inc
  rement primary key, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)"

**What is cause of this error? Help me please.**

Answer (score 0):

Do not use lenght value, just create tinyint with default value:

```
$table->tinyInteger('actual')->default(0);
```

Comment: thank you! I use your instruction and it's save me. One more thanks!

Comment: p.s. 
@Martin I made +1 to your answer but my reputation not enough for visual result of it.